# iTerm2 hide/show like Guake

Tags: command-line, terminal, iterm2

I have looked around for a short time trying to see if there is any way that iTerm2 has the options to hide/show like Guake does on Ubuntu? I have fallen in love with this option using Guake and would love to see an option like this for Mac.

Thank you for any references you can give to me.

Rob

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The latest version of Iterm2 does this almost out of the box.

After installing it, check that you have 2 profiles, one called **Default** and one called **hotkey window**. If you have to go to the Keys tab, select the hotkey you want to use (I have it set to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>) and select the hotkey window as the profile to show and hide.

Comment: it's a pity that iterm shows up when I do a `command+tab`, if it weren't there and my hot key set to F1, it would have been great. do you know any trick to do that?

Comment: @NishchalGautam this is 2 years later, and I'm not sure if you're interested anymore, but others might be. In case you want to remove it from `Cmd+Tab`, you can go to `Preferences > Appearance` and at the end check the box that says `Exclude from Dock and Cmd+Tab Application Switcher`. And you can set the Hot Key to `F1` (or any other) in `Preferences > Keys > Hotkey` in the `Hotkey` field.

Comment: sold my mac and got a linux laptop, best decision of my life :D but thanks for the info :)

Comment: @msamprz I was able to do as you say. Now when I press F12 I can show/hide iterm. But if iterm2 is shown and I click outside the window, iterm2 gets hidden. Is there a way to prevent it ? I want it to be shown unless I press again F12.

Comment: @ErnestPoldrige If I understood you correctly, [have a look at this](https://superuser.com/a/1259726/579607), however, I currently have Windows temporarily for now, so I haven't tested this. Kindly let me know how it goes.

Comment: any way to stop the hotkey window from disappearing when it loses focus? I love the way it works except for that. It should just stay on screen like a normal window.

Answer (score 37):

As Ron mentioned in his answer, the "hotkey window" feature has got you covered.

After installing iTerm2, check that you have two profiles in the `Profiles > Open Profiles` panel: one called "Default" and one called "hotkey window".

If you don't have the "*Hotkey Window*" profile listed in the profile settings:

1. Open `iTerm2 > Preferences` and go to the Keys tab.
2. Locate the hotkey window options in the bottom left of the Preferences dialog.
3. Ensure that both the *"Show/hide iTerm2 with a system-wide hotkey"* and the *"Hotkey toggles a dedicated window with profile"* checkboxes are checked/marked. This should create the "Hotkey Window" profile for you automatically.
4. Set the hotkey you want to use in the Input Box (I have it set to CRTL-^, just cuz it reminds me of the old Quake II times) and select `Hotkey Window` as the profile to show and hide in the dropdown list.
5. Enjoy!

   [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48796/iterm-as-a-slide-out-terminal-from-the-top-of-the-screen?newreg=be3c946c2e414192895d9bdf2b3dca14) in the Ask Different community illustrates the above steps.

Additionally Nishchal Gautam asks, as a comment to Ron's answer, if you can hide apps from the `command + tab` listing of apps running. Too bad I don't have enough reputation to place this response as a direct comment to the current answer, but here is the answer: iTerm2 supports this as part of it's "Advanced" options:

[image: Advanced options: hide iTerm2]

There's also [an answer to that question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92004/is-there-a-way-to-hide-certain-apps-from-the-cmdtab-menu) in the Ask different community, to do it manually. Both options achieve the same, the former being the easy way.

---

**Note**: I'm just adding this new answer with the link for a more complete reference because, in comparison with Rob's answer, it states very clear that you need to tick both check boxes and select the "hotkey window" profile in the dropdown list at the bottom for the feature to fully enable the functionality - the link is a bit clearer than Ron, if you ask me: he does indeed mention everything you need to get going, but I had issues understanding the wording and had to further search why my settings weren't properly configured. That link made me realize that I overlooked the second checkbox. Silly me and my lame reading comprehension skills.

**Note2**: I just figured out that Ron's answer doesn't cover the most common case for when you don't have the profile already created. I've sent an edit request.

Comment: Do you know how to make it appear on the display wich currently has mouse pointer in it when using hotkey?

Comment: @OlehZiniak: Preferences > Profiles > Hotkey Window > Window > Screen "Screen with cursor". Don't have a multi-monitor setup at the time of writing, but the naming is suspiciously accurate. Please confirm!

Comment: @OlehZiniak Back to my multi-monitor setup: the "screen with cursor" option does the trick for me. Running iTerm2 3.3.4.

Answer (score 14):

As of iTerm 3.1.x and up, achieving the Guake effect is much easier since a lot of these items have been moved to their dedicated submenus. There are two methods that you can use (separately or simultaneously) that you can choose that will best suit your needs. Both of these methods can be accessed at `Preferences > Keys > Hotkey`:

[image: Hotkey Preferences]

1. **Dedicated HotKey Window:** Automatically creates the `Hotkey Window` and displays the preferences for the profile. This is the same as `Profiles > {Profile Name} > Keys > Hotkey Window` and selecting `A hotkey opens a dedicated window with this profile`. **This option will display an isolated instance of iTerm instead of everything that was previously open.**
2. **Show/hide all windows with a system-wide hotkey:** As the name suggests, this shows / hides everything iTerm, including the `Preferences` window. The advantage of setting this hotkey is to quickly access all of your iTerm windows when you have the `Exclude from Dock` option selected.
   *Note: Not sure if this is a bug or a preference, but if your Preferences window is open and iTerm loses focus, the first time you input the hotkey combo only brings the latest active Profile. Pressing two more times brings back the Preferences window.*

Folks at iTerm have also made it simpler to access `Exclude from Dock` setting. Simply head over to `Appearance > General` and find the option `Exclude from Dock` at the bottom.

[image: Exclude from Dock option]

This will provide you with a pretty nifty Menu Bar Icon from which you can also access your `Settings` or `Bring All Windows to Front`.

Answer (score 11):

As of early 2020, after a little frustration while looking for it in the old place... I've found the **hotkey** in yet another place in preferences:

[image]

Comment: This should be the correct answer for this question as of today.

Answer (score 6):

there is a worked solution:

https://www.sharmaprakash.com.np/guake-like-dropdown-terminal-in-mac/

> Go to iterm2 preference
>
> Assuming you are now running iterm2; on the top left you will see
>   iterm2 written just beside apple logo, click there and go to
>   preference.
>
> Click on keys tab
>
> Create a dedicated hotkey window
>
> On the bottom of this window you will see a botton that says create a
>   dedicated hotkey window. Click on that and you will see a new window
>   where you can configure hotkey(shortcut) for dropdown terminal.
>
> Assign hotkey
>
> (On a newly opened window) Click on input box on the side of HotKey
>   and then click the combination you want to assign to open iterm2.

Comment: he has marked *this question* as reference